# No browser is sending Authorization info in header

Tags: url, google-chrome, http-headers, fiddler, basic-authentication

I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters) and it would appear 'easy' to send the credentials in the URL. For example:

> http://gooduser:secretpassword@www.example.com/webcallback?foo=bar

This is all well and good but *it doesnt work*. I've turned fiddler on and for Chrome the `Authorization` header isnt sent. It appears to exhibit the same behaviour for other browsers (i've got a breakpoint on the server and no Authorize header turns up for Firefox,Safari or IE either)

How to make it better?

Comment: Hi, I just ran into the same question. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I was surprised that I see the Authorization header sent for a Basic autorization in chrome. Others still fail

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled across this while researching various basic auth implementations.

Browsers generally only send basic auth if they receive a `401` challenge response from the server ([more on basic auth protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)). If the endpoint in question accepts both authenticated and non-authenticated users, then a browser-based request will likely never be prompted for the auth parameters.

The easiest way to test this type of setup is to send a curl request (which sends the authentication parameters regardless) to your server endpoint and validate receipt of the `authorization` header:

`curl 'http://gooduser:secretpassword@www.example.com/webcallback?foo=bar'`

Answer (score 0):

OK so after much searching and experimenting the approach

```
http://gooduser:secretpassword@www.example.com/webcallback?foo=bar
```

does work.
However one needs to be careful to ensure that the secret password DOES NOT contain any special characters. Use a password containing only letters and numbers and a hypen(if you must) and it should work.