# Automatically mirroring a Gitlab repo onto Github on push

Tags: github, gitlab

I'm looking for a way to automatically mirror my Gitlab repos to Github, on push. I use Gitlab repos as my main repos, and would rather have to push to only one remote. But, I want my code to be browsable on Github also.

I found similar questions on StackOverflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962872/how-to-create-a-gitlab-webhook-to-update-a-mirror-repo-on-github).

But the answers are always the same: one should add a custom post-receive git hook to the gitlab repo. This requires a shell access to the server running Gitlab. As I'm hosting a community edition Gitlab for many users, and not only me, they can't have easy access to a shell (and this isn't the most user-friendly way to do this), so it does not fit my needs.

I thought about two ways to implement it:

- Either a MirrorOnPush project service, implementing such a git hook in Ruby, as the EmailOnPush project service currently do.
- Or use a custom server to clone and push the repo, using a webhook.

The first one seems to be the cleaner to me, but I can't find any doc about Gitlab project service and code structure… On the other hand, the second is a bad and ugly hack, but is almost straightforward.

I'd rather implement a project service to handle it. Do you have any doc or leads on how to write a project service for Gitlab (without having to read all the Gitlab source code, as there seems to be no dev doc…) ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gitlab repository mirroring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring) While this is a slightly more restricted, all possible answers are mentioned there, and are likely to be so in the future.

Comment: The other question is more single-user centric, I think. But yes, the answers are there… This post was also about finding doc for services, but this does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> one should add a custom `post-receive` git hook to the gitlab repo.

Actually, that was the best solution, up until 7.x GitLab, as I detailed in "[Gitlab repository mirroring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14291690/6309)";

A true [project service](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/app/models/project_services) for repo mirroring is requested, but not voted up enough: suggestion: [suggestion 4614663](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4614663-automatic-push-to-remote-mirror-repo-after-push-to).
The main documentations remains:

- the [app models project services](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/app/models/project_services) folder,
- the [spec models project services](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/spec/models) folder,
- the [`doc/project_services`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc/project_services),
- the [project services scenarios](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/features/project/service.feature).

This isn't much, as [the OP noted before](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8473).

Since it That leaves you with the hack approach.