# How to keep one Gitlab repo in sync with the other [mirroring][gitlab-gitlab]

Tags: git, gitlab, mirroring

How do I mirror one gitlab repository with the another.

I have a repository which should be in sync with the protected branches of another repository.

Comment: Mirroring from GitLab to GitHub over SSH connection is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73728220/3586084).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing a [Gitlab server hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#create-a-server-hook-for-a-repository) like the following for **ALL REPOSITORIES** (look at the posted official guide link):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#create-a-server-hook-for-a-repository

# Encode path slashes with dots.

FIXED_PROJECT_PATH=$(echo ${GL_PROJECT_PATH} | sed -r 's:/:\.:g')

# Mirror the repository, even if does not yet exist.

PROJECT_URI=<<GITLAB_MIRROR_URL>>/${FIXED_PROJECT_PATH}.git

git push --mirror ${PROJECT_URI}
exit 0 # Force successfully execution
```

**NB:** remember to subsitute `<<GITLAB_MIRROR_URL>>` with your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitLab [mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/) capability to achieve that, it's built-in the platform.