# How do I setup GitLab like mirroring in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a collection of projects from different people in different personal repositories I want to upload into to a college GitHub organisation. Ideally, the organisation will be read only and will directly mirror the personal repos.

While, creating 2 push URLs for a repo is an option, I feel this approach will have problems for collaboration as one would have to set a user as a collaborator for both the college organisation and the personal repo. Thus, I want to implement a mirroring system [similar to what GitLab does](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html). Is there anyway I can do this using GitHub using webhooks if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You would need webhook only if those projects (you want to mirror) are themselves on GitHub.

If they are on their own private server (like a self-hosted one), a [post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21998477/6309) would be enough to push what has just been received to a GitHub mirror repo.
If those server are self-hosted GitLab ones, [you can configure them to push to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38302815/6309).

If not, you need to install a service like [`Fiware/tools.Webhook`](https://github.com/Fiware/tools.Webhook) on a server in order to listen to a webhook payload and trigger the mirroring.

Comment: Yes, the projects which I want to mirror are all on personal GitHub repos. How would I go about mirroring from here?

Comment: @shortstheory add a post-receive hook on your GitHub server side, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21998477/6309