# How to use gitlab to test and deploy websites

Tags: git, web, webserver, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have set up a remote server with git and installed gitlab as my repository management tool. I develop php websites so I want to know if there is a way to view these websites on the server because all you can see normally is source code and I want to know if the website is working or not. I have read a bit about web hooks but I am not entirely sure if that is what I need to do or if it is something else. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to check out a working copy to the web root on the server (or wherever you want to view it from), as you won't be able to use the repository.

There's an explanation of how to do that here: [Git Post-Receive Hook for Website Staging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried that but I get a permissions denied error when I try this git push web +master:refs/heads/master

Comment: When do you get that error? When trying to push from your working copy to the repo, or at some other time?

Answer (score 1):

Every answer to the following question is also an answer to this one: [Gitlab repository mirroring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring)

You get errors because of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26483811/895245 GitLab automatically manages hooks for you and uses that as an important part of the system.