# How to create bot user with no or duplicate email?

Tags: gitlab

I'm using gitlab 7.4.3

I want to create a user to sync a git repo with gitlab periodically. It's actually a git-svn checkout of a svn tree, so I plan to in cron run 'git svn fetch' and 'git push gitlab' every few minutes.

But I don't want this actively to show up as my activity. So I want to create a user, something like 'svnbot', and do the pushing as that user.

My problem is that I cannot create a user because I already have a user, and gitlab is requiring email addresses to be unique.

Ideally the user would have the same email as my account, so that any email it would receive goes to me. Also, having no email address at all would also be fine for my purposes. I don't want the email to leave the local domain, so I can't just put in a gmail account, and my email server doesn't support the "+" trick.

I have admin rights to the gitlab server, but not to the email servers, and I would prefer to not have to bother the email admins with this problem.

Comment: I don't know about the SVN, but do you really need to use a bot? Why not some of the techniques mentioned at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring ? Most will run arbitrary commands on push.

Comment: @CiroSantilli But there's nothing that I want to happen on push. I just want to do the pushing with a different user. I don't want it to appear as though my normal user account is doing all of these pushes.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you need to contact your email admins. You can almost certainly get by with having them create an alias for your email account, e.g. 'gitlab-svn-bot@example.com'.