# GIT: Mirror and Sync Remote Repository (Forum)

Tags: git, repository

I need some help.

Is it possible to have 1 directory with different remote repository?
And, Is it possible 2 remote repo is a mirror to each other. if repo 1 receives a push code, repo 2 must be automatically updated on what repo 1 has. (vice versa).

Comment: Please elaborate "Is it possible to have 1 directory with different remote repository? ". I am not able to understand what exactly you want! :)

Comment: I mean I just want to sync REPO 1 and REPO 2 what ever changes to them vice versa will sync vice versa :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible!

You can do it easily using the post-recieve hook. The post-recieve hook is triggered whenever there is a push to the repository.

So when you push to Repo1 it will push the same thing to Repo2 and vice-versa.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring) might help you.

This way things can be kept synchronized.

Hope it helps! :)