# Central git to push changes automatically to multiple git repos in different servers

Tags: git, automation

I have the following scenario:

Server A is the main server where developers are pushing the code and merging it to the master line. Now this particular git line is to be synched across the multiple servers say Server B/C/D/E where I just need the repo to be synched.

Is there an automative technique to do the same? Kindly suggest.
Thanks!

Comment: What Git repository are you using (e.g. GitHub, BitBucket)?  I believe these services already synch your repo across multiple servers for many reasons (e.g. backup, ease of access).

Comment: Hi Tim, I am using gitlab for the same.

Comment: I think this is related to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring ... Tim let me know if this solution can be approached ?