# Sync gitolite and gitlab

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, gitolite

I have an upcoming project wherein the vendor uses Gitolite and the client uses Gitlab. The vendor and client both need to make changes and keep both the repositories in sync the code frequently. This isn't a simple migration of code with one time commit history import. The commit history needs to be in sync regularly as well. Is there a way this model can work and what are the factors to keep in mind to build this setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitlab repository mirroring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the vendor uses Gitolite

That just means the authorization layer is managed by Gitolite. Other than that, it is just a bare git repo.
The same applies to GitLab (which provides also a listener, and a wiki)

Simply mirroring the GitLab is not enough.

What you need is a local Git repo with two remotes (one referencing each bare repo), in which you fetch from both and merge changes locally, resolving the differences and pushing back to those bare repos.