# Gitlab daily backup to self-hosted instance

Tags: git, gitlab, self-hosting

My company and I extensively rely on Gitlab for all our daily requirement mapping (issues, new features and bugs) and checking-in code. With the recent outage that Gitlab faced, we were locked out, and couldn't do anything and were scared that we had lost all our issues. We not want a standalone backup of our Gitlab data. I was wondering if I can host a standalone **community edition Gitlab** version on a server just as a backup? We will continue to use GitLab.com (**enterprise edition**) for all of our daily activities, but would like a daily backup (code, branches, issues, wiki, milestones, everything!) copied over to our standalone "**community edition"** server instance.

**Is this possible? and how?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitlab repository mirroring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring) -- although that's just for the repo itself and not the extras.

Comment: @josh Lee. Repo mirroring can be set up from the command line as well I can also take a snapshot every day and store it in S3. But I'm looking for a complete solution. One that also backs up the issues, tickets, wikis milestones etc.

Answer (score 1):

Simply methods won't work. [Backup/restore doc](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md#note) claims that

> We backup GitLab.com and make sure your data is secure, but you can't
>   use these methods to export / backup your data yourself from
>   GitLab.com.

Anyway, there is an option to [export the project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html)

> The following items will be exported:
>
> - Project and wiki repositories
> - Project uploads
> - Project configuration including web hooks and services
> - **Issues with comments, merge requests with diffs and comments, labels, milestones, snippets, and other project entities**
>
> The following items will NOT be exported:
>
> - Job traces and artifacts
> - LFS objects
> - Container registry images
> - CI variables
> - Any encrypted tokens

But remember, that

> Importing will not be possible if the import instance version differs
>   from that of the exporter.

So keep in mind to update your CE instance regularly. As I see, this is possible to migrate from EE to CE and vice-versa, but [sometimes it may be problematic](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18957).

To sum up, it's not a complete solution. Furthermore, it must be automated on your own.  I recommend starting using GitLab on your server with own administration and so on.

Comment: Hey, this is a great summary and exactly what I needed to get started. Just a note: the issue that you point out regarding the "problematic migration from EE to CE"  has been resolved. I read through it and they say that EE columns that are not in CE will be ignored. If that's what you meant then great, cuz I can live with it. If not I would like if you could elaborate on the "problematic" bit..

Comment: @leo That's what I meant - in newest versions it's fixed. I just wanted to put emphasis on being careful in migrating between two, not exactly the same systems.