# How to delivery new code version into several node.js servers?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have some `node.js` servers hosted by `google cloud compute engine`. As the instances running the servers are created by an `Instance Group` there is a Load Balancer in front of them and their IP change frequently.

When the `Instance Group` creates the instance from the Instance Templates, the boot script pulls the current version using `gitlab` and the process runs ok.

Is there a way to upload versions in all instance group using a single command line, something that could make all the instances run `git pull` initiated by centralised requests?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do so, but I see two straightforward solutions to your problem depending on your needs:

1. Since you are running the servers on a Linux instance is to setup a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) at startup time that from that moment on with the frequency you prefer pull the code from your repository through the classical `git pull`.

   This solution is not extremely elegant, but few lines are needed and it is quite effective. Obviously if check the new code each T seconds the servers risk to run different code for at maximum for T seconds, this depending on the nature of your workload might be an issue.
2. There is a built in features to do so, the [Repository Mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html). Your mirror at GitLab will be updated automatically. Honestly I have never implemented this solution, but you can check the following StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring) that could guide you through the process.