# Mirroring AOSP code from Gerrit to Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, android-source, gerrit, repo

I have few doubts regarding hosting repo tool maintained AOSP code on Gitlab.

I have mirrored the AOSP code on my local PC which was maintained by the repo tool and Gerrit on an another remote server. As our company is currently using the Gitlab for source code management and review, I need to host this on our internal Gitlab server.

Queries:

1) Is it possible to upload the mirrored repo with all branches,tags and commits to the gitlab? If yes, how?

2) How we can link the repo upload command with gitlab review?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitlab repository mirroring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288288/gitlab-repository-mirroring)

Comment: Thanks kelvin, we can upload the single mirror git projects to gitlab with all tags and branches. But in our case , we have android source code which consist of many git projects which is managed by repo tool and manifest.xml file. Could you please help on the same?