# How to send a correct authorization header for basic authentication

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to POST data from my API but I can't pass the basic authentication.

I try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: http://theappurl.com/api/v1/method/,
  data: {},
  crossDomain: true,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic [REDACTED]');
  }
});
```

My server configuration response is:

```
response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST"
response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
```

The headers that I get is:

**Request Headers**

```
OPTIONS /api/v1/token-auth/ HTTP/1.1
Host: theappurl.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, authorization, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

**Response header**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2013 01:29:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 597
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted"
```

I guess the server configuration is good because I can access to API from the *[Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)* (Chrome Extension)

Any suggestions?

PD:
The header that I get from Advanced REST client is:

```
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31
    Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
    Authorization: Basic [REDACTED]
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: es,en;q=0.8
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

and

```
    Server: nginx/1.1.19 
    Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2013 01:07:18 GMT 
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
    Connection: keep-alive
    Vary: Accept, Cookie 
    Allow: POST, OPTIONS 
    X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

sending OPTION method

Comment: I realize this post is long dead, but I just want to point out in case you're not aware that by posting your Authorization: header, you've essentially posted your password in the clear. The string of gibberish there is just the base64 encoding of your username:password, so everyone can see your password. Hopefully you realized this and used a dummy password here :)

Comment: This works fine with ssrs report server 2017. It hides the password and username in the URL.

Comment: @Lexelby: The username is "the user" and the password is "and the password" in Spanish.  So I'm guessing these aren't real credentials.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can include the user and password as part of the URL:

```
http://user:passwd@www.server.com/index.html
```

see this URL, for more

[HTTP Basic Authentication credentials passed in URL and encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption)

of course, you'll need the username password, it's not `'Basic hashstring`.

hope this helps...

Comment: That solution won't work for Android's Native Browser (Pre KitKat). The username/login form will still popup for your user, so be careful.

Comment: This method exposes the username and password to anyone listening on the network or devices...

Comment: @Adam hash string is also not safe

Comment: This method exposes username/password in the browser history since it's part of the URL.  In addition, it's likely to get logged on the server since requests logging includes the query string.  It's better to include user/pass as part of the "Authorization" header.  Search on http basic authentication.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Passing it as a url is not a header.

Comment: @JemiloII How do you think it works in the background?  The browser generates the authorization header for you.  It absolutely does get sent as a header.

Comment: @user1483903 Logged on the server as part of the query string?  Instead of telling people to search on basic auth, why don't you perform the same search yourself?  Fire up a packet sniffer to see how this really works before adding comments that are not correct.

Comment: @Adam All basic auth is exposed to anyone listening on the network, unless you're doing this over TLS/SSL.

Comment: @Brad because the question specifically states send a correct header, it doesn't ask for browser magic. Plus, sending it as a header eliminates the url from being seen in the user's history. It's not a good thing to have credentials in an easily searchable format.

Comment: @JemiloII AJAX URLs don't appear in history.  And, it's not magic... it's a well understood standard.  This *does* answer the question in an alternative way, and is a perfectly valid answer, even if it isn't appropriate for your specific situation.

Comment: Ideally we'd use the Authorization header to pass in the Base64 encoded username:password as Basic. This approach is not ideal given it's much more natural for a programatic AJAX client to add request headers than to concatenate things onto an URL

Comment: Can't you read, he asked about POST request. And you suggest him to use GET request.

Comment: This is no longer supported by major browsers and is deprecated

Comment: downvote reason: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication. Towards the end of the article, it mentions that `The use of these URLs is deprecated`

Comment: This is like someone asking how to fix their car, and you pasted instructions on bicycle maintenance

Comment: According to RFC3986 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 Use of the format "user:password" in the userinfo field is deprecated.

Answer (score 89):

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication , here is how to do Basic auth with a header instead of putting the username and password in the URL. Note that this still doesn't hide the username or password from anyone with access to the network or this JS code (e.g. a user executing it in a browser):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: http://theappurl.com/api/v1/method/,
  data: {},
  crossDomain: true,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(YOUR_USERNAME + ':' + YOUR_PASSWORD))))
  }
});
```

Comment: Note: A window.btoa polyfill such as Base64.js will be required for this feature to work in IE6,7,8,9. Also unescape is deprecated as per ECMAScript v3.

Comment: @Techbrunch you are mistaken, seanp2k's example works very well, it uses a very known trick to decode Unicode characters to ASCII, it actually uses the fact that (un)escape does not support Unicode, but (dec)encodeURIComponent does..

Answer (score 63):

## NodeJS answer:

In case you wanted to do it with NodeJS: make a GET to JSON endpoint with `Authorization` header and get a `Promise` back:

First

```
npm install --save request request-promise
```

([see on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)) and then in your `.js` file:

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');

var user = 'user';
var password = 'password';

var base64encodedData = Buffer.from(user + ':' + password).toString('base64');

requestPromise.get({
  uri: 'https://example.org/whatever',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64encodedData
  },
  json: true
})
.then(function ok(jsonData) {
  console.dir(jsonData);
})
.catch(function fail(error) {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: Thank you this worked in my react application which used "fetch"

Comment: Thanks man! Worked in react with fetch also

Answer (score 18):

If you are in a browser environment you can also use [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa).

`btoa` is a function which takes a string as argument and produces a Base64 encoded ASCII string. Its supported by [97% of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=btoa).

Example:

```
> "Basic " + btoa("billy"+":"+"secretpassword")
< "Basic YmlsbHk6c2VjcmV0cGFzc3dvcmQ="
```

You can then add `Basic YmlsbHk6c2VjcmV0cGFzc3dvcmQ=` to the `authorization` header.

Note that the usual caveats about HTTP BASIC auth apply, most importantly if you do not send your traffic over https an eavesdropped can simply decode the Base64 encoded string thus obtaining your password.

[This security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https) answer gives a good overview of some of the downsides.

Answer (score 3):

no need to use user and password as part of the URL

you can try this

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("user:passwd".getBytes());

String USER_PASS = new String(encodedBytes);

HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get(url).addHeader("Authorization", USER_PASS).build();
```

Answer (score 3):

**PHP - curl**:

```php
$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
...
```

**PHP - POST in WordPress**:

```php
$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';
...
wp_remote_post('https://...some...api...endpoint...', array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password")
  )
));
...
```