# How to get around 401 errors with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

So I am trying to scrape a webpage but there is a user/password field required before the page can be accessed (I think it's one of those .htaccess things? not sure what you call them). I know the user/pass normally but can't figure out how to bind it in the code. How do I send the user/pass when I access the page?

If I do it without the user/pass I just get a 401 Unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the authentication is requested by the server, rather than the webpage, you could try sending the credentials in the page URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18264755/3457753