# Using Postman to test Web Api 2 with [Authorization]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, postman

Edit: I apparently need to fumble around just to realize what question I'm actually trying to ask..

I am using MVC5 and EF6 to build a local web application and am trying to test my web api 2s with Postman. I'm fairly new to http and ASP.NET and am wondering if there exists a tool to make api requests without too much authorization configuration. I understand that entity framework saves validation tokens in the browser, but I can't seem to find a good Chrome extension that will utilize the validation token to test CRUD operations before building out the UI to use them.

I should add this is a large practice project - I'm learning to swim in EF, not dependent on airtight security at this point.

I've tried following the instructions here:

[ASP.NET Web API Authorization with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081232/asp-net-web-api-authorization-with-postman?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but I can't seem to get Postman and IIS to get along.

Comment: I am not clear what you want.
here are two things you should avoid,
1. cookie/session should not be a thing in api. you should manage it in different way
2. session based login will not work on api. so, build a token based authentication. thanks

Comment: I do apologize, I'm fairly new to ASP.NET. As I understand, it uses token based auth by default. Since I haven't implemented a way to retrieve this particular db model in the UI yet, I am trying to make a `GET` request using Postman which should do the same thing, so long as I'm logged in as an authorized user.

Comment: You are logged in not in the postman but in the browser. so, postman takes you to login page. The reason is, in api session can't be store based on client.

Comment: I've tried generating a Basic Authorization header using the dummy account credentials and the get the same results. I guess my real question here is how to use postman :/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suddenly realize that I'm using the stand alone Postman, not the Chrome extension like I have in the past. Thanks Abdur