# Thunderbird, SoGo Connector, Address book and multiple accounts with different connection

Tags: contacts, thunderbird, connector, carddav

I have problems trying to connect to many **external sources** in my address book with Thunderbird. It manage passwords by linking them to their base url. But what if with the same base url, I have two accounts with different connection?

After I've installed **SoGo Connector** (CardDav), I created a new distant address book with this sort of information:

- url: https://sync.my.server/addressbook1
- user: u1
- pass: u1

Everything was fine and the sync was perfect.

Now I want to connect to an other one:

- url: https://sync.my.server/addressbook2
- user: u2
- pass: u2

And there comes the bad part. Thunderbird check if sync.my.server already exists (which is true) and try to connect with u1/u1. Obviously, it will not work...

I found a way to manage this problem with calendars, by going to the advanced configuration editor and changing the calendar.network.multirealm to true. But this doesn't seem to apply to contacts.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I believe this question is better directed at the SoGo community.

Comment: If you still have trouble with this, I have just written a detailed tutorial about this. You can find it here: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/05/05/owncloud-mit-thunderbird-und-android-verbinden-komplettanleitung/#Thunderbird_Contacts_Birthday good luck.

Comment: Nice of you to share that documentation kwoxer and I do read German but with all the screenshots blurred out for essential information it doesn't make much sense. You'd be much better off setting up a demo instance where you don't have to blur much out for your screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Baïkal](http://baikal-server.com/) and I had the same problem (different users having their own calendar and address book but which sometimes must share them within a Thunderbird session).

Thunderbird stores credentials in a host-based basis, so there's a workaround using a different subdomain when new calendar/address book must be added to TB. I have Baikal running in a Debian box with Bind9 and Apache, so adding a new DNS entry and a ServerAlias in the virtual host configuration solves it, for example:

- dav.example.com
- dav2.example.com (alias of the first one, associated with the second CardDAV/CalDAV username/pass)

The same could be achieved using the hostname and the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday, but I found a solution - now I'm using several calendars and several address books from different accounts (differing credentials) on the same server. I also have to use an ssl proxy so I couldn't create two different subdomains.

Do not use Thunderbird's password saving option.
Include the credentials in the url instead (see [this question on how this works with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption)).

So using SOGo Connector you need to create two calendars for users Adam and Eve with these addresses:

```
https://Adam:adamspassword@sslproxy.com/paradise.com/DavServer/Adam/defaultcalendar
https://Eve:evespassword@sslproxy.com/paradise.com/DavServer/Eve/defaultcalendar
```

Mind though that you can't change any password afterwards without deleting and recreating the corresponding calendar in Lightning.

Use the same trick for the address books in Thunderbird, although these actually let you change the url without recreating the address book.

---

**EDIT: This does not work reliably on all platforms!**

I did not manage to overcome my persisting connection problems. I suspect that somewhere in the code of Thunderbird / Lightning / Sogo it is not possible to have two sets of credentials for the same domain.

Instead, I created two calendars in one account. This is less secure / isolated, but it works reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your carddav server, you can try granting access to other resources.

If you're using one Thunderbird instance with two different accounts on the same server, I suggest you clean up your setup.

One Thunderbird profile = One account per server/domain.

Then, if u1 needs access to addressbook2, you can grant read and/or write permissions, and the server will allow him/her to access it with his/her own credentials.

I currently use this setup with many Thunderbirds connecting to one davical server with many calendars and addressbooks. No need for multirealms or anything...

Answer (score 0):

On Thunderbird go to Edit → Preferences → Advanced → Config Editor and set calendar.network.multirealm to true. This will active the multi account for **calendars only**.

For contacts I solved with different servers path. 
Ex:

- example.com/addressbooks/users/.......
- mail.example.com/addressbooks/users/.......