# Postman localhost Authentication

Tags: api, laravel, postman

I created an API with [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) 4 that I want to test so I'm using [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en). When I input my username, my password and my URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/stores/public/locator/api/service/v1/store
```

A popup shows and tells me to enter my username and password for localhost:80. How do I solve this problem?

**Here is the route** :

```
Route::resource('store', 'StoreController');

Route::filter('Apiauth', function()
{
 return Auth::basic("username");
);

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'locator/api/service/v1', 'before'=> 'Apiauth'),  function()
{
Route::resource('store', 'StoreController');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include basic authentication in

```
http://username:passwordd@www.server.com/route
```

[HTTP Basic Authentication credentials passed in URL and encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption)