# Git Push - Username and password in the remote url

Tags: git, github, push

As I understand password prompt when pushing to github can be avoided by adding the username:password in the [remote push url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github).

```
https://you:password@github.com/you/example.git
```

Is this a github specific arrangement or can this format be used (`https://username:password@somedomain.org/repo.git`) with any git remote?

Comment: The `user:password@host` pattern is not git-specific; it is [Basic HTTP Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2716990/390819). I think it does not work on `ssh://` git remotes.

Comment: Thanks @w0lf! Is there any way to automate pushing to remote repository?

Comment: `git push` is a command that can be entered in the command line or in scripts. So, yes, you can automate it in any way you like.

Comment: What I meant was is there a way to automate pushing without prompting for a username and password? Let's say the username and the password is available at the code?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that. You might want to try using SSH keys instead, if possible.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @wolf! Could you add the first comment as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a github specific arrangement?

It's not Github specific; this is actually [Basic HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). The `user:password@host` trick is a [way of specifying the BA credentials in the URL](https://serverfault.com/a/371918/85448).

> ...can this format be used (https://username:password@somedomain.org/repo.git) with any git remote?

It works only for remotes that use the HTTP protocol. For SSH remotes you'll have to use SSH Keys instead.

Answer (score 7):

A more secured way to authenticate you through GitHub than put your password in the remote URL would be, if you use HTTPS, to generate a new token in [this](https://github.com/settings/tokens) GitHub page and then build your remote URL like this:

```
https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<username>/<project_name>.git
```

Answer (score 3):

Git push should not show the password [since Git 2.9.3 (August 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891849/6309), but, to be on the safe side, Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) improves that even more:

Before, the remote-http transport did not anonymize URLs reported in its error
messages at places.

See [commit c1284b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1284b21f2436de24c9559fcc5f4badb04f47773) (04 Mar 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 764bd20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/764bd200e1077b44f291973a623debccf151fcb2), 16 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `curl`: anonymize URLs in error messages and warnings

It anonymizes URLs (read: strips them of user names and especially passwords) in user-facing error messages and warnings.

---

Before Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), error and verbose trace messages from "`git push`" did not redact credential material embedded in URLs.

See [commit d192fa5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d192fa50067d1630312a966aba22c90139812fc5) (24 Apr 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2c42fb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c42fb76531f4565b5434e46102e6d85a0861738), 01 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`push`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d192fa50067d1630312a966aba22c90139812fc5): anonymize URLs in error messages and warnings
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
>
> Just like [47abd85ba0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47abd85ba06ed7209d1caa3e5ac7cc6b232bece4) ("`fetch`: Strip usernames from url's before storing them", 2009-04-17, Git v1.6.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/983e9b63aecf1923ef5809fe13ed107105627262)) and later [882d49ca5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/882d49ca5cb6a584a37ab0266b8720b5b0bf2101) ("`push`: anonymize URL in status output", 2016-07-13, Git v2.10.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d54ad9cd44231c33f5776f67afea924c9a589b3) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c6d1f9807c67532e7fb545a944b064faff0f70b)), and even later [c1284b21f243](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1284b21f2436de24c9559fcc5f4badb04f47773) ("`curl`: anonymize URLs in error messages and warnings", 2019-03-04, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/764bd200e1077b44f291973a623debccf151fcb2) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffac537e6cbbf934b08745a378932722df287a53)) this change anonymizes URLs (read: strips them of user names and especially passwords) in user-facing error messages and warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your local Git remember the GitHub credentials:

> If you're cloning GitHub repositories using HTTPS, you can use a credential helper to tell Git to remember your GitHub username and password every time it talks to GitHub.

Chekout [this article on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-all).

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, using credentials in a remote URL like `https://you:password@github.com/you/example.git` is not the best practice, and the user should be reminded of that.

Git 2.37 (Q3 2022) offers such a warning: the "**`transfer.credentialsInUrl`**<del>`fetch.credentialsInUrl`</del>" configuration variable controls what happens when a URL with embedded login credential is used.

It was initially called `fetch.credentialsInUrl`:

See [commit 6dcbdc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dcbdc0d6616d7fbd2445aa2237b22e3c172ea85) (06 Jun 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 11698e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11698e551ce0590af6d7ce1f5b683eca27e68ab3), 13 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dcbdc0d6616d7fbd2445aa2237b22e3c172ea85): create fetch.credentialsInUrl config
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Users sometimes provide a "`username:password`" combination in their plaintext URLs.
> Since Git stores these URLs in plaintext in the `.git/config` file, this is a very insecure way of storing these credentials.
> Credential managers are a more secure way of storing this information.
>
> System administrators might want to prevent this kind of use by users on their machines.
>
> Create a new "`fetch.credentialsInUrl`" config option and teach Git to warn or die when seeing a URL with this kind of information.
> The warning anonymizes the sensitive information of the URL to be clear about the issue.

(again, renamed below as **`transfer.credentialsInUrl`**)

> This change currently defaults the behavior to "`allow`" which does nothing with these URLs.
> We can consider changing this behavior to "warn" by default if we wish.
> At that time, we may want to add some advice about setting `fetch.credentialsInUrl=ignore` for users who still want to follow this pattern (and not receive the warning).
>
> An earlier version of this change injected the logic into `url_normalize()` in [`urlmatch.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6dcbdc0d6616d7fbd2445aa2237b22e3c172ea85/urlmatch.c).
> While most code paths that parse URLs eventually normalize the URL, that normalization does not happen early enough in the stack to avoid attempting connections to the URL first.
> By inserting a check into the remote validation, we identify the issue before making a connection.
>
> However, we can reuse the parsing information from `url_normalize()` in order to benefit from its well-worn parsing logic.
> We can use the struct `url_info` that is created in that method to replace the password with "`<redacted>`" in our error messages.
> This comes with a slight downside that the normalized URL might look slightly different from the input URL (for instance, the normalized version adds a closing slash).
> This should not hinder users figuring out what the problem is and being able to fix the issue.
>
> As an attempt to ensure the parsing logic did not catch any unintentional cases, I modified this change locally to to use the "die" option by default.
> Running the test suite succeeds except for the explicit username:password URLs used in t5550-http-fetch-dumb.sh and t5541-http-push-smart.sh.
> This means that all other tested URLs did not trigger this logic.
>
> The tests show that the proper error messages appear (or do not appear), but also count the number of error messages.
> When only warning, each process validates the remote URL and outputs a warning.
> This happens twice for clone, three times for fetch, and once for push.

The warning or error will be:

```
URL '%s' uses plaintext credentials
```

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), rename `fetch.credentialsInUrl` to `transfer.credentialsInUrl` as the single configuration variable should work both in pushing and fetching.

See [commit 7281c19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7281c196b1166f1c00df33948c67b0ef81ba63a9), [commit 4a169da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a169da280aa6d22bdf0cf5baea65f47bd363a3a) (15 Jun 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7f5a382](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f5a382aa5eb54509a4de4d399d8b35c48d91c65), 17 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`transfer doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7281c196b1166f1c00df33948c67b0ef81ba63a9): move fetch.credentialsInUrl to "transfer" config namespace
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Rename the "fetch.credentialsInUrl" configuration variable introduced in [6dcbdc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dcbdc0d6616d7fbd2445aa2237b22e3c172ea85) ("`remote`: create fetch.credentialsInUrl config", 2022-06-06, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11698e551ce0590af6d7ce1f5b683eca27e68ab3)) to "transfer".
>
> There are existing exceptions, but generally speaking the "`<namespace>.<var>`" configuration should only apply to command described in the "namespace" (and its sub-commands, so e.g. "clone.*" or "fetch.*" might also configure "git-remote-https").
>
> But in the case of "fetch.credentialsInUrl" we've got a configuration variable that configures the behavior of all of "clone", "push" and "fetch", someone adjusting "fetch.*" configuration won't expect to have the behavior of "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7281c196b1166f1c00df33948c67b0ef81ba63a9/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> altered, especially as we have the pre-existing "`{transfer,fetch,receive}.fsckObjects`", which configures different parts of the transfer dialog.
>
> So let's move this configuration variable to the "`transfer`" namespace before it's exposed in a release.
> We could add all of "`{transfer,fetch,pull}.credentialsInUrl`" at some other time, but once we have "`fetch`" configure "`pull`" such an arrangement would would be a confusing mess, as we'd at least need to have "`fetch`" configure "`push`" (but not the other way around), or change existing behavior.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7281c196b1166f1c00df33948c67b0ef81ba63a9/Documentation/config/transfer.txt#L1-L38):

> ### `transfer.credentialsInUrl`
>
> A configured URL can contain plaintext credentials in the form
> `<protocol>://<user>:<password>@<domain>/<path>`.
>
> You may want
> to warn or forbid the use of such configuration (in favor of
> using [`git credential`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential)). >
> This will be used on
> [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push),
> and any other direct use of the configured URL.
>
> Note that this is currently limited to detecting credentials in
> `remote.<name>.url` configuration, it won't detect credentials in
> `remote.<name>.pushurl` configuration.
>
> You might want to enable this to prevent inadvertent credentials
> exposure, e.g. because:
>
> - The OS or system where you're running git may not provide way way or
>   otherwise allow you to configure the permissions of the
>   configuration file where the username and/or password are stored.
> - Even if it does, having such data stored "at rest" might expose you
>   in other ways, e.g. a backup process might copy the data to another
>   system.
> - The git programs will pass the full URL to one another as arguments
>   on the command-line, meaning the credentials will be exposed to oher
>   users on OS's or systems that allow other users to see the full
>   process list of other users. On linux the "hidepid" setting
>   documented in procfs(5) allows for configuring this behavior.
>
> If such concerns don't apply to you then you probably don't need to be
> concerned about credentials exposure due to storing that sensitive
> data in git's configuration files.
>
> If you do want to use this, set
> `transfer.credentialsInUrl` to one of these values:
>
> - `allow` (default): Git will proceed with its activity without warning.
> - `warn`: Git will write a warning message to `stderr` when parsing a URL
>   with a plaintext credential.
> - `die`: Git will write a failure message to `stderr` when parsing a URL
>   with a plaintext credential.