# Username and password in command for git push

Tags: git, git-bash

It's possible to clone down a git repository, specifying username and password in the command. Example:

`git clone https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git`

Is it is possible to also specify the username and password when pushing? So that, for example, running `git push origin --all` will then output asking for a password. I want this in one command.

(I am aware of the ability to set up keys and other solutions, but I want to know if there is a way to just keep using username and password with one command.) I am running Git Bash on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Do you find solution for `git commit`?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Yes, you can do

`git push https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git --all`

in this case `https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git` replace the `origin` in `git push origin --all`

To see more options for `git push`, try `git help push`

Comment: Note that this will store username and password *in plaintext* in the git configuration.

Comment: instead of plain password you can use password hash

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk What kind of hash do you use? Does this work for Github?

Comment: what happen if password contain `@` ?

Comment: Recommend enclosing the complete path with `' '`, for example: `git push 'https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git'`

Comment: Enclosing the complete path with ' ' will give you this error (Windows command line): fatal: I don't handle protocol ''https'

Comment: if you are using this command on windows - wait for few seconds - git bash will give prompt for username and password - and once you enter new username and password - it stores again

Comment: https://username@myrepository.biz/file.git => this to prevent storing password in plane text and thus every time you push it ask you to enter password

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem. Note that the username and email will be saved in the `config` file of that git repo.

Comment: does not work on git bash on windows if username is email : fatal: unable to access 'https://gmail.com:password@git.heroku.com/silbeni.git/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: @RahulSharma if the password contains @ then you can use %40 ( url encoder)

Comment: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: This is useful if you wanna do git push in a github actions workflow without using external apps, using GITHUB_TOKEN as password.

Comment: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.

Answer (score 47):

I used below format

`git push https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git --all`

and if your password or username contain @ replace it with %40

Comment: You can even use WebUtility.UrlEncode(password) to get that %40

Comment: for php users use this `urlencode($password)` this will encode all the special characters not only `@`.

Comment: Unsafe. If somebody intercepts and decrypts your sent message he gets your credentials... Use SSH key pairs...

Comment: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.

Answer (score 29):

For anyone having issues with passwords with special chars just omit the password and it will prompt you for it:

```
git push https://YOUR_GIT_USERNAME@github.com/YOUR_GIT_USERNAME/yourGitFileName.git
```

Comment: It seems as if your answer is the only one on the entire web stating straight how to only give the username.

Comment: @PreetSangha did you change `YOUR_GIT_USERNAME` to your usermame, and if you don't use github.com did you change it to something else?  Did you change `yourGitFileName.git` to something else?

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 Apologies for my comment. It was caused by another permission issue.

Comment: It didn't prompt
Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

Comment: 2023 still works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. you can use a personal access token instead. like following push command:

```
git push https://<User Name>:<Token>@github.com/<User Name>/<Your Repository>.git
```

[Link to how to create an access token](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: Use the following command for clone:
git clone https://<User Name>:<Token>@github.com/<Repository Owner User Name>/<Your Repository>.git

Comment: It is not recommended method. Use Git Credential Manager instead.
https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/tree/v2.0.785

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), the last argument of the `git push` command can be the repository that you want to push to:

```
    git push [--all | --mirror | --tags] [-n | --dry-run] [--receive-pack=<git-receive-pack>]
             [--repo=<repository>] [-f | --force] [--prune] [-v | --verbose] [-u | --set-upstream]
             [<repository> [<refspec>…]]
```

And the `repository` parameter can be either a *URL* or a remote name.

So you can specify username and password the same way as you do in your example of `clone` command.

Comment: That seems suitable, but when I add the git repo with username and password as an argument, as the example, it still prompts for the password.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible but, before git 2.9.3 (august 2016), a `git push` would print the full url used when pushing back to the cloned repo.
That would include your username and password!

But no more: See [commit 68f3c07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68f3c079fe87caab2e116fd9a48bbdedc54be026) (20 Jul 2016), and [commit 882d49c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/882d49ca5cb6a584a37ab0266b8720b5b0bf2101) (14 Jul 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 71076e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71076e11cda645c08f5c9f269e02ed28e47d5c4a), 08 Aug 2016)</sup>

> ### `push`: anonymize URL in status output
>
> [Commit 47abd85 (fetch: Strip usernames from url's before storing them, 2009-04-17, Git 1.6.4)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47abd85ba06ed7209d1caa3e5ac7cc6b232bece4) taught fetch to anonymize URLs.
>   The primary purpose there was to avoid sticking passwords in merge-commit messages, but as a side effect, we also avoid printing them to stderr.
>
> The push side does not have the merge-commit problem, but **it probably should avoid printing them to stderr**. We can reuse the same anonymizing function.
>
> Note that for this to come up, the credentials would have to appear either on the command line or in a git config file, neither of which is particularly secure.
>   So people *should* be switching to using credential helpers instead, which
>   makes this problem go away.
>
> But that's no excuse not to improve the situation for people who for whatever reason end up using credentials embedded in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Git will not store the password when you use URLs like that. Instead, it will just store the username, so it only needs to prompt you for the password the next time. As explained in the [manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_avoiding_repetition), to store the password, you should use an external *credential helper*. For Windows, you can use the [Windows Credential Store for Git](https://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/). This helper is also included by default in [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/).

When using it, your password will automatically be remembered, so you only need to enter it once. So when you clone, you will be asked for your password, and then every further communication with the remote will not prompt you for your password again. Instead, the credential helper will provide Git with the authentication.

This of course only works for authentication via https; for ssh access (`git@host.com/repository.git`) you use SSH keys and those you can remember using `ssh-agent` (or PuTTY’s pageant if you’re using plink).

Comment: "I am aware of the ability to set up keys and other solutions, but I want to know if there is a way to just keep using username and password with one command."

Comment: @Marvin I’m aware of that remark, however I didn’t just want to submit a two-sentence answer, so I included information for other users who might not be just interested in connecting via HTTPS.

Comment: It still doesn't answer his question, though.

Answer (score 0):

6.5 years later, multi factor authorization is almost everywhere, and you'd probably use a token. For github, see [Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with [GitCredentialManager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager)

It is a terminal utility for git. When running `git push`, it will open a prompt to provide credentials.
Please find more details on their GitHub Repo.
https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager

It is easy to install and use.