# Passing parameters to shell input from python

Tags: python, django, git

I am working on a Django application (and in Python I'm rather the beginner ) that will push some code to the Git repository (any remote).

Everything works fine on my local machine, but here I have the keychain and SSH configured.

However, as soon as the app will go into production, that will not work, as everyone would have to use the same user to push the code (which is not possible unfortunately), or configure ssh for everyone, which also is a no-go.

So far I have managed to create this:

```
call(["git", "init"])
call(["git", "remote", "add", "origin", request["repo_url"]])
call(["git", "add", "-A"])
call(["git", "commit", "-m", "Initial commit"])
call(["git", "push", "-u", "origin", "master"])
```

And, as stated above, this works if I push from my local dev machine with configured Git and keychain.

But now, how do I input the password after the `push` command? Is this even possible?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776439/username-and-password-in-command-for-git-push

Comment: Rather than using `call`, you may want to have a look at pygit: http://www.pygit2.org/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an url:

```
call(["git", "push", "https://username:password@host/repo.git"])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) although I had to modify slightly the code to set the `user.name` and `user.email` in the `git config` for it to pass correct committer data