# Is it possible to Git merge / push using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, bitbucket

I am trying to create a Jenkins workflow using a Jenkinsfile. All I want it to do is monitor the 'develop' branch for changes. When a change occurs, I want it to git tag and merge to master. I am using the GitSCM Step but the only thing that it appears to support is git clone. I don't want to have to shell out to do the tag / merge but I see no way around it. Does anyone know if this is possible? I am using BitBucket (on-prem) for my Git server.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment because `GitPublisher` plugin, the plugin previously responsible for tagging/merging/pushing in freestyle jobs, has not been updated to be compatible with Jenkins pipelines. You can follow that issue on both the [pipeline plugins compatibility page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md#build-steps-and-post-build-actions) and the dedicated [GitPublisher Jira issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335).

So it seems the only option you have is to actually shell out your tag/merge commands... However, note that you can still benefit from some Jenkins built-in capabilities such as the use of credentials for your Git repo, which make it pretty straightforward to then tag / merge following your needs.

Example check-out :

```
git url: "ssh://jenkins@your-git-repo:12345/your-git-project.git",
    credentialsId: 'jenkins_ssh_key',
    branch: develop
```

Then the tag / merge / push will be pretty straightforward :

```
sh 'git tag -a tagName -m "Your tag comment"'
sh 'git merge develop'
sh 'git commit -am "Merged develop branch to master'
sh "git push origin master"
```

I hope that one day GitPublisher will be released in a pipeline-compatible version, but for now this workaround should do.

Comment: Really?  When I try the above answer (using ssh credential just live above) and try to do anything that communicates with the remote I 'Permission denied (publicly).'  it is able to checkout the code from git as above, but the credentials are not cached

Comment: Let's continue with your specific problem on your [dedicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39237910/702954)

Answer (score 41):

If what you're after are the git credentials you can use the SSH Agent plugin like in this link: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335?focusedCommentId=260925&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-260925

```
sshagent(['git-credentials-id']) {
  sh "git push origin master"
}
```

Comment: this is still asking for username and password

Comment: Make sure you have login via SSH enabled on your git and you have added the correct SSH keys to your Jenkins. This has worked for me and 6 other people without need for any additional config.

Comment: Ensure you've actually cloned over ssh as well. If you're cloning over HTTPs, you need to use user/pass on the trip back as well.

Answer (score 24):

In my case I was forced to work with HTTPS. I solved it by:

1. Creating a username/password credential **bitbucketUsernamePassword**.
2. Using that credential to checkout.
3. Setting credential.helper before doing checkout.
4. Doing a **git checkout branch** to get a local branch tracking remote.

Then I am able to push things with **git push** after that.

Like this:

```
sh 'git config --global credential.helper cache'
sh 'git config --global push.default simple'

checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: branch]],
    extensions: [
        [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: true]
    ],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [
        [ credentialsId: 'bitbucketUsernamePassword', url: cloneUrl]
    ]
])
sh "git checkout ${branch}" //To get a local branch tracking remote
```

Then I can do things like:

```
sh 'git push'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great for https! I also had to add `sh "git config --global user.email"` && `sh "git config --global user.name"` to be able to commit and push.

Answer (score 17):

This thread was really helpful. My Jenkins credentials are username/password so I used:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'fixed',
                 usernameVariable: 'username',
                 passwordVariable: 'password')]){
    sh("git push http://$username:$password@git.corp.mycompany.com/repo")
}
```

The username and password are both obscured in the log:

```
+ git push http://****:****@git.corp.mycompany.com/repo
```

Answer (score 8):

I've had to do a similar task and managed to get it to work with a variation of this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335?focusedCommentId=320383&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-320383

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'ci', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
    sh 'echo ssh -i $SSH_KEY -l git -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \\"\\$@\\" > local_ssh.sh'
    sh 'chmod +x local_ssh.sh'
    withEnv(['GIT_SSH=./local_ssh.sh']) {
        sh 'git push origin develop'
    }
}
```

Whereas `ci` is the id of the credential you setup within Jenkins. The path to the ssh key becomes available as the environment variable `SSH_KEY` and local_ssh.sh is added to current directory.

Comment: this worked for me on "CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 2.263.2.3-rolling" when nothing else here worked. hero!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is!!
After struggling for days, I ended up with these simple code block for scripted pipeline script which worked for me.

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: '<credential-id>', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
   sh("git push origin <local-branch>:<remote-branch>")
}
```

Enjoyy!!

Comment: SSH_KEY is not used by git nor ssh. This does not work.

Comment: With respect to any SCM, there are two ways of authentication, https and ssh. For ssh authentication, keys are required. May be you are using this in some other manner.

Comment: For ssh it is of no use to have private key available in file named by SSH_KEY environment variable when nothing uses SSH_KEY within the withCredentials. This question has other answers that make use of SSH_KEY by sh("GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ${SSH_KEY}' git ...") or such. Those can work. This answer contains no working solution.

Comment: The credentialId mentioned is a credential created in Jenkins as 'SSH Username with private key'. This is a pre-requisite and the rest is internally handled by Jenkins. I expected that this is already known to the answer seeker.

And it has worked for me and an upvote of 4, I think means that it has worked for 4 of us. :)

Comment: @LittyPhilip, are you sure? In my case, the command uses the key under "/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa", which is the default one on the server and not the mentioned one in the Credentials Plugin. Is it possible that in your case both keys are equal?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I want to push to a CodeCommit repository through SSH. `sshagent` doesn't work because it does not set `User`. This eventually did the job:

```java
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: CODECOMMIT_CREDENTIALS_ID, keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY', usernameVariable: 'SSH_USER')]) {
    withEnv(["GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=${SSH_USER} -i ${SSH_KEY}"]) {
        sh 'git push ${CODECOMMIT_URL} ${COMMIT_ID}:refs/heads/${BRANCH}'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution with help of basic Jenkins and git functionality

```
    stage('Git Push'){
    steps{
        script{
            GIT_CREDS = credentials(<git creds id>)
            sh '''
                git add .
                git commit -m "push to git"
                git push https://${GIT_CREDS_USR}:${GIT_CREDS_PSW}@bitbucket.org/<your repo>.git <branch>
            '''
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/
[Username and password in command for git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776439/username-and-password-in-command-for-git-push)

Answer (score 4):

Litty Philips' answer got me most of the way but I also needed to define GIT_SSH_COMMAND.

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: '<credential-id>', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
   sh """
   GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -i $SSH_KEY"
   git push origin <local-branch>:<remote-branch>
   """
}
```

Comment: This snippet is also giving me an error that `GIT_SSH_COMMAND: not found` in the Jenkins declarative pipeline. But replacing the line of specifying the environment variable with the following line fixed that issue: `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i $SSH_KEY' `. It is working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Lately, the git plugin add this command:

```
stage('git push') {
    steps {
        withCredentials([
            gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'github', gitToolName: 'Default')
        ]) {
            sh "git push"
        }
    }
}
```

Could not find the related documentation. I found that out in the "Pipeline Syntax" helper found in any Pipeline job.

Comment: [The doc of the _Credentials Binding Plugin_](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).

Answer (score 2):

Got this working with sshagent on blue ocean (which uses https authorisation)

```
sshagent(credentials: ["406ef572-9598-45ee-8d39-9c9a227a9227"]) {
                    def repository = "git@" + env.GIT_URL.replaceFirst(".+://", "").replaceFirst("/", ":")
                    sh("git remote set-url origin $repository")
                    sh("git tag --force build-${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
                    sh("git push --force origin build-${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
                }
```

Comment: don't use force push. you could kill your entire git history