# jenkins pipeline cannot check code into git

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins pipeline project I can check code out from git fine... but we need to do some git checkins and the credentials apparently are not cached.

```
    stage 'Checkout'
    git url: 'git@bitbucket.org:myproj.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: '012ce21d-e920-44ee-b6f7-08df8ab41de0', variable: 'CREDENTIALS'
    sh('git push') <---- fails with Permission denied (public key).
```

here is sample output:

```
Entering stage Checkout
Proceeding
[Pipeline] git
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:myproj # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:myproj.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:myproj.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision cc35402c6b39e8a1f8d55a831d2d10215d47ccd0 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f cc35402c6b39e8a1f8d55a831d2d10215d47ccd0 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master cc35402c6b39e8a1f8d55a831d2d10215d47ccd0
 > git rev-list cc35402c6b39e8a1f8d55a831d2d10215d47ccd0 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] sh
[myproj] Running shell script
+ git push --set-upstream origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.192.143.2' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

anyone have a good solution to this?

thanks

Comment: you are using Jenkins out from docker ?

Comment: the slaves run in docker, don't think that matters though

Comment: I recently had a similar problem on Windows slaves... Just to be sure, could you tell us the result of your pipeline if you run it from the master ? Also, have you configured correct repository permissions ? From your git@gitbucket url it says that a git user should have right access to your repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer is to use the sshagent jenkins plugin:

http://getmesh.io/Blog/Jenkins+2+Pipeline+101

this plugin injects a SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable for git access

Comment: I don't think this is "the answer". It's a workaround but you shouldn't need sshagent to do that, I personnaly don't have `sshagent` command in my pipeline and `git push` is working just fine. I do however have my private key in Jenkins home (`/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa`) and associated credentials `jenkins_ssh_key` that points to this private key...

Comment: is that directory on the slave?

Comment: Yes I have it on both the slave and the master and both are working just fine !

Comment: what if you are bound to http(s)? @l-cotonea's answer will help...

Answer (score 6):

Extracted from the Jenkins pipeline samples repository, we can do that avoid using sshagent: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/push-git-repo/pushGitRepo.Groovy

Then for your exemple, the solution should be using the Credentials binding plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) and use this snippet:

```groovy
stage ('Checkout') {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '012ce21d-e920-44ee-b6f7-08df8ab41de0', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
    sh("git tag -a some_tag -m 'Jenkins'")
    sh('git push git://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@bitbucket.org:myproj.git')
  }
}
```