# How to find a particular text in entire codebase - Groovy Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Within a Jenkins-Groovy pipelines I want to do the following:

1. Clone a particular GitLab based Code repo.
2. Then within this repo I want to find out all the files where there is a particular string. Example: "`find_me`"
3. Once found I want to change all these files from `find_me` to `found_me`.
4. Then commit these changes to the GitLab repo.

Step 4 above maybe I can find out myself, but I am struggling on **how to do the 2nd and 3rd steps** mentioned above.

Can anyone please suggest what can be the best way to do this?

Comment: [What](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) have you [tried so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Sorry for asking like this. I am pretty new to Groovy Jenkins and DevOps world and I didn't know how to go about it. I was not looking for an exact solution but some idea on how I could go about implementing it. If you can suggest anything that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Pipeline: SCM Step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/)
2. [`findFiles`: Find files in the workspace](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace)
3. [`readFile`: Read file from workspace](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace), [`writeFile`: Write file to workspace](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace), [`prependToFile`: Create a file (if not already exist) in the workspace, and prepend given content to that file](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#prependtofile-create-a-file-if-not-already-exist-in-the-workspace-and-prepend-given-content-to-that-file).
4. You can't commit to a GitLab repo directly from within Jenkins. You add/commit/merge locally, then you push. See, for instance: [Is it possible to Git merge / push using Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38769976/1744774).