# How to git push in jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: git, jenkins, pipeline, commit

Hi I want to push in Jenkins pipeline script.

I registered git id/pw in Jenkins credentials.

I succeeded git clone.
This is git clone script

`git branch: "develop", credentialsId: "mygitid", url: "mygiturl"`

Now I want to commit & push.. but I don't know how to do this..
Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to [push from a Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38769976/6309), using the [Credentials Binding pugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)

```yaml
stage('git push') {
    steps {
        withCredentials([
            gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'mygitid', gitToolName: 'Default')
        ]) {
            sh '''
                 # modify some files
                 git add .
                 git commit -m "register work"
                 git push
            '''
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes you remain on the default cloned branch (usually '`main`')

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it working good .  Can I ask question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it working good .  Can I ask question? Push result is  'remote : To create a merge request for develop, visit:' is it working success?? Because my coworker fail to git pull..

Comment: @seok0.2 The push work. Which means a pull should too, provided you are on the same branch. The PR message regards merging `develop` to the `main` branch. But in your case, as long as your colleague does a `git switch develop` first, and then a `git pull`, the code pushed should be present on their working tree.