# execute git pull with username and password

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is there way to put username and password in the command with git pull,
to avoid password message.
for example

```
git pull -u ahmeditman -p 123456  #this example to explain .
```

It is okay to use

```
git pull http://ahmeditmna:123456@xxxxx.git
```

But it will pull from Master Branch, but if i need to pull from dev Branch ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and password in command for git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776439/username-and-password-in-command-for-git-push)

Comment: thank You, I updated the post, Could you check it ?

Comment: Is there some reason you want to use HTTPS instead of SSH? An SSH key may solve your problem neatly.

Comment: @AhmedMItman, switch to your local `dev` branch and pull. It should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It is okay to use
>
> ```
> git pull http://ahmeditmna:123456@xxxxx.git
> ```

I think you mean `git clone http://ahmeditmna:123456@xxxxx.git`

---

Technically speaking, yes. `http://username:password@domain/path` is a valid URL part of HTTP(S) protocol.

But is that safe or should you do it? No.

Well first, it's better to use HTTPS, if you are pushing / pulling from a public repository it won't be a problem since data is already public, but if it's a private repository your data could be read by an attacker.

But the more important part is anyone having access to the copy of your repository would be able to read your credentials. Just try it (*I took the first Python related repository for this example..*):

```
cd /tmp/
git clone 'https://username:password@bitbucket.org/mshibly/python-examples-from-intro-to-python-course.git'
cd python-examples-from-intro-to-python-course/
git remote -v
```

`git remote -v` list repository's remotes URL, let's see:

```
origin   https://username:password@bitbucket.org/mshibly/python-examples-from-intro-to-python-course.git (fetch)
origin   https://username:password@bitbucket.org/mshibly/python-examples-from-intro-to-python-course.git (push)
```

As you can see, your credentials are here, waiting to be read.

And that's even worst if you use this on a server since depending on your general configuration you can find your credentials in logs. Not speaking about the fact you may end by scripting this and have your credentials into a script you may commit and / or store on someone's else server.

The point here is there are not good reasons to do this, but there a plenty of good reasons to not.

**No, it's not ok to do this.**
I advise you to spend some hours learning how SSH works and configuring your OS.

Answer (score 5):

If you override the remote origin URL (`git config remote.origin.url`) to `http://ahmeditmna:123456@xxxxx.git`, like:

```
git remote set-url origin http://ahmeditmna:123456@xxxxx.git
```

Pull will work without prompting for password on any kind of branch.