# How does the drone clone the repository?

Tags: gitlab, repository, git-clone, drone.io

For gitlab, if I get the client_id and client_secret, how can I clone the repository, just like what drone does. Is there any API or something？

Answer (score 0):

The is no "GitLab API" for cloning, since [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) native command is there for that.

You could then try and clone with:

```
git clone https://oauth2:TOKEN@ANY_GIT_PROVIDER_DOMAIN/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_REPO.git
```

(assuming the `client_secret` is the token)

Or:

```
git clone https://client_id:TOKEN@ANY_GIT_PROVIDER_DOMAIN/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_REPO.git
```

(replace client_id by the actual value)

---

However, this is considered bad practice, and [Git 2.37 (Q3 2022) will display the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72649714/6309):

```
URL '%s' uses plaintext credentials
```

It is better to cache those credentials:

```
git config --global credential.helper
xxx <= note that value

printf "host=gitlab.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=client_d\npassword=client_secret" | \
git credential-xxx store
```

(replace `xxx`, `client_id` and `client_secret` by their actual values)

And then

```
git clone https://client_id@ANY_GIT_PROVIDER_DOMAIN/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_REPO.git
```

No more token/secret in the URL.