# Securing OPKG repository without tampering with the OPKG sources

Tags: security, repository, embedded-linux, package-managers, opkg

I am trying to secure my OPKG repository (not the package list or each package, the repository itself). So far I got nothing on this searching a lot for a solution. Someone was saying that it got this type of security by changing the OPKG, but I am wondering isn't there a solution that doesn't have to touch the OPKG sources? Any suggestions of what I could try?

Comment: OPKG can support basic http auth if you compile it with curl instead of the default wget - is this what you're aiming at?

Answer (score 0):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867769/securing-an-opkg-repository/36259617#36259617) on how to make OPKG use basic auth over Http (no source modification required).
If you need a secure repository as well take a look at [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Opkg+Repositories).