# From Windows Forms, Open Default Browser with Basic Authentication Credentials

Tags: .net, winforms, basic-authentication, system.diagnostics

**Goal**
Using .NET Framework 4.0, prevent multiple requests for log-in credentials.

---

**Setup**
I have a Windows Form application that utilizes [System.Net.HTTP.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to authenticate on another domain.

With basic authentication, I want to use those same credentials to open the default browser to a specific URL (same domain as above).

---

**Tried**
[System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToDefaultBrowser, userName, passwordAsSecureString, URL)
```

---

**Result**

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
  NativeErrorCode=1326
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName, String userName, SecureString password, String domain)
```

---

**Questions**

- Is this possible?
- Is my implementation wrong?
- Is there a better way?

Comment: I found the answer to this question on another SO post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption?lq=1