# How to grant access to a request htacces?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I've got a website which (I think) is protected by .htaccess. When you're going on it a pop-up pop and ask you for your credentials.

I know my id and my password.

I would like to create an `<iframe>` on an HTML5 page where my src is my website and my id and my password will be automatically entered.

The website is not mine, it's a website from my school. When you're going on a specified link first you've got a pop-up which appears:

> Authentication required. The server server123 requires a username and password

I type my ids and then a download of a file is fired off. I would like to put my ids in parameter so I can just click on my page and the download is fired automatically.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more details. What code base does your website run on (such as PHP)? What have you researched so far? What has or hasn't worked for you in your research? Examples of what you want to do or what you've tried would all be helpful.

Comment: Go ahead and edit your original question with your extra details when you're ready. That will be a lot easier to read than if you were to add more comments. Thank you very much!

Comment: Open the browser inspector to see what the fields are called, make a `curl` request and save the response.

Comment: If this is http basic auth, you might try http://stackoverflow.com/q/2716990/1741542

Comment: Just to clarify, so you're building a page that is going to take you through to the other site which is already protected, and you're looking for an approach on how to authenticate with basic auth?