# Cordova Hosted Web App with Basic Authentication

Tags: cordova, basic-authentication, visual-studio-cordova, manifoldjs

I would like to create a hosted web app in Cordova. However, in my case, the hosted web app is behind a Basic Authentication.

How do I make the hosted web app to appear in Cordova client as if it wasn't behind a Basic Auth? Or how do I add the Basic Auth header all requests from Cordova Client?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such setting in Cordova.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption

Comment: @Linda Z, I don't think my question is a duplicate of what you've mentioned. Not all browser works with user:pass in url. I'm asking for http header using basic auth. Furthermore, my question is very Cordova specific