# Microsoft Edge WebNavigation redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm working with Microsoft Edge extension.

I would to redirect users if they navigate in a specific url.
In my background.js script I have this:

```
browser.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(
  function(details) {
   if(details.url.indexOf("url_path") > -1){
     alert("caught");
     window.location = "http://new_url.com";
   }
  }    
);
```

The alert work, but not the redirect. What I'm doing wrong?
Also is a good idea pass user e pass for http auth in the redirect?
For example: windows.location = "http://user:pass@new_url.com" ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`browser.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate` is called in background page, when you call `window.location = xxx`, the window means the background page window, which is not the current web page, that's why the redirection doesn't work.

To redirect web request, take a look at [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest). It also provides sample code about how to redirect user navigation.

As for password for http auth in the url, as long as you use **https**, [the entire communication is encrypted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption)