# Selenium 2.53 is not throwing exception when browser is not invoked using driver.get() & driver. Navigate.To()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-authentication

I used selenium 2.53.1 and tried invoking browser but browser throws Windows authentication pop up.  Once Windows authentication pop up comes driver.get() will throw exception in selenium 2.42 but the same scenario is not working in 2.53. Driver is not throwing any exception and stays idle for long time in 2.53

Browser used firefox.
Eg: url
driver. Get("https://www.engprod-character.net/");
Windows Authentication pop up window occur expection requires user credentials.

In selenium 2.42 : as driver is unable to invoke browser it throws exception, so that i catch that exception and handle the authentication pop up by using robot fw code. 
Browser : firefox 29

In selenium 2.53: driver is not throwing any exception. So i couldn't able to handle it.
Browser : Firefox 46

Why selenium 2.53 is not throwing exception. Do we have any alternate other than using autoIT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Windows Authentication username and password is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-windows-authentication-username-and-password-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you set system property ("webdriver.gecko.driver"). Otherwise Firefox could be opened without any further action.

I can't open your link https://www.engprod-character.net/ please check it too.

I don't know autoit. I only can say that Selenium is a web testig-framework working for

- Java
- C#
- Ruby
- Javascript
- Python
- Perl

Hope this helps?

EDIT: And I recommend to handle a popup in another way. I don't know the source code of your test object but if it's a java popup Selenium can't read it.

In this case, use

```
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("<username>");
action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

and in the same way send Password and ENTER.

Another way is to overcome the authentication by adding credentials to UR, described in [HTTP Basic Authentication credentials passed in URL and encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716990/http-basic-authentication-credentials-passed-in-url-and-encryption)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

driver.get() throws exception when Windows pageload timeout is expired it throws exception then we can catch tge exception and execute the robot class code to hansle Windows authentication pop up